# Plot multiple dots over a range of coordinates on a graph with Manim?

Tags: python-3.x, coordinates, manim

Is there a way to plot multiple dots over a range, specifying multiple coordinates? Does this need to be manually completed or could it be done another way?

```
class Scatter(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        ax = (
            Axes(
                x_range=[0, 9, 3],
                y_range=[0, 9, 3],
                x_length=7,
                y_length=5,
                tips=False,
            )
            .to_edge(DOWN)
            .add_coordinates()
            .set_color(WHITE)
        )

    for x in range(4, 5):
        for y in range(3, 5):
            point = ax.coords_to_point([x, y, 0])
            dot = Dot(point)
            self.add(ax, dot)
```

Appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Axes.plot_line_graph`](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.graphing.coordinate_systems.Axes.html?highlight=axes#manim.mobject.graphing.coordinate_systems.Axes.plot_line_graph) method and only add the vertices to the scene:

```
plot = ax.plot_line_graph(x_coords, y_coords)
self.add(plot["vertex_dots"])
```